# MVC viewmodel and a linq query

Tags: linq, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-5

I finally (after 4 weeks) got a result for a MVC5 project and it went well. 
Now I'm trying to "limit" the number of results and it's flagging an error:

```
'Stoopid' is a type, which is not valid in the given context
'Student' is a type, which is not valid in the given context
```

Here's the model:

```
namespace viewModelA
{
    public class Teacher
    {
        public int TeacherId { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string EnrollmentNo { get; set; }
    }
    public class Stoopid
    {
        [Key]
        public int StoopID { get; set; }
        public DateTime stopDt { get; set; }
    }
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Stoopid> Stoopids { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this is the linq query - notice that Teacher is fine, but Student and Stoopid are NOT. And they are all in the same .cs file. Am I missing something?

```
var result = (from t in Teacher
        join s in  Student on t.TeacherId equals s.StudentId
        join st in Stoopid on s.StudentId equals st.StoopID
         where t.TeacherId == 2
         select new
         {
          TeacherID= t.TeacherId,
          Code = t.Code,
           t.Name,
           s.StudentId,
          sCode =s.Code,
          sName=s.Name,
          stopDt= st.stopDt
         })
```

Edit: I added the relevant code to the HomeController. I also ran this thru LINQPad5 and it works fine so I don't know what's the deal
[HomeController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyR4D.png)

Comment: are you trying to return a View Model that contains the 3 types?

Comment: Yes - I'm returning the "ViewModel"..that's why I was so confused.

Comment: Are you using a code first or database first approach ? if using a code first approach are you certain that you have defined the data sets ?

Comment: Steffsww- I using code first. I added the code for the HomeController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing the class names in your Linq query, which is why it is throwing that error. You need to reference the actual List objects instead.

```
var result = (from t in mymodel.Teachers
    join s in mymodel.Students on t.TeacherId equals s.StudentId
    join st in mymodel.Stoopids on s.StudentId equals st.StoopID
     where t.TeacherId == 2
     select new
     {
      TeacherID= t.TeacherId,
      Code = t.Code,
       t.Name,
       s.StudentId,
      sCode =s.Code,
      sName=s.Name,
      stopDt= st.stopDt
     })
```